# How do I enable WSL in pycharm interpreter settings?

Tags: python, troubleshooting, pycharm

Currently, I have Ubuntu installed on Windows 10 as a WSL where I installed python and want to use that as an interpreter in Pycharm on Windows 10. I go to the add interpreter settings and expect to see a WSL option as seen in the [JetBrains guide.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html)

As seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNOBs.png), there is a WSL option, but that option doesn't exist on my screen as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxBGl.png).

How can I enable this option?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure "Python WSL Support" and "WSL Support Framework" plugins are enabled in **Settings | Plugins | Installed**.

Comment: Did you  figure out how to enable wsl option in PyCharm?

Answer (score 3):

Remote Python interpreters ( SSH, Vagrant, WSL (only for Windows)).

Supported only in PyCharm Professional.   <<---here